# Drawing route between two GPS coordinates

Tags: android

I understand I have to take latitudes and longitudes at a certain period of time using on location changed method but how will I draw a line between two points...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Consider taking the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn the format of a successful question.

Comment: post some code please..

Comment: Extremely Sorry I forgot to change the Subject

Comment: private double calcLatitude(Location location, double oldlatitude) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  double newlatitude = oldlatitude;
  
  if(oldlatitude == -1)
  {
   oldlatitude = newlatitude;
  }
  
  if(location.getAccuracy() <= 0.5)
  {
   newlatitude = (2 * oldlatitude + location.getLatitude())
                 / (2 + 1);
         lastLocationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }
  
  if (lastLocationTime >= 2) {
         newlatitude = location.getLatitude();
     }
  
  return newlatitude;
 }
I am using this code to calculate latitude and longitude at a interval of 2 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for drawing line between two points using maps v2:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: Thank you I will go through the tutorial.